# Not getting scroll bar when rotating the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi Guys I have two problems:

1. when rotating the screen (to landscape) I am missing my controls.
2. I have back and next buttons. I want to position them at the very end of my activity.
   how to do that?

My code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".TeamActivity" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home Club" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Home Team" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Away Club" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Away Team" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"       
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"            
            android:onClick="WeatherConditionsActivity"
            android:text="Next" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:onClick="OpenVenueActivity"
            android:text="Back" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

kindly help.

Comment: Guys pls ignore the second question. I have solved using android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Answer (score 1):

Surround the entire top-level

```
<LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

in a

```
<ScrollView>
    (Your <LinearLayout></LinearLayout> goes here)
</ScrollView>
```

But you could also consider a res/layout-land/mylayout.xml (matching res/layout/mylayout.xml) to use a different layout in landscape view that perhaps avoids the need to scroll.